# the least value for $m\ge 2005$ such that $a_{m+1}-1\mid a^2_m-1$

Tags: number-theory

If we assume that  $a_1=3$  and for every $n\ge1$  we assume that $a_{n+1}=(n+1)\cdot a_n-n$.How to find the least value for $m\ge 2005$ such that $a_{m+1}-1\mid a^2_m-1$

Comment: What have you tried until now? Your question doesn't show that you put any effort into solving it.

Comment: With some small numbers examples or some effort the OP can probably answer this him/herself.

Answer (score -1):

Note that 
$$ a_{n+1}-1=(n+1)(a_n-1) $$
so the question becomes:

Find the least value $m \geq 2005 $ such that $m+1 | a_m+1$

With a small amount of effort, the first formula can give you an explicit formula for $a_n$.

Comment: Was this a bad answer? Why was it downvoted?